# How can I filter a JavaScript array by element first letter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops, search

Let say I want to search the tickers array and return all of the items in the array that start with S and then write them to the sCompanies = [].

Anyone have any idea how I go about this using a for or while loop?

```
// Iterate through this list of tickers to build your new array:
let tickers = ['A', 'SAS', 'SADS' 'ZUMZ'];

//console.log(tickers);



// Define your empty sCompanies array here:

//Maybe need to use const sComapnies = [] ?
let sCompanies = []


// Write your loop here:


for (i = 0; i < tickers.length; i++) {
  console.log(tickers[i]);
  
}



// Define sLength here:

sLength = 'test';

/*
// These lines will log your new array and its length to the console:
console.log(sCompanies);
console.log(sLength);*/
```

Comment: This question is very similar to many others regarding JavaScript arrays on SO. What have you tried to accomplish your goal? I don't see any code that would do that.

Comment: You've specifically requested a solution involving "a for or while loop". Is that a stated requirement of (what appears to be a) homework assignment? Bigger picture, it doesn't look like you've made any attempt to solve this problem yourself. You should always do that for future problems because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or homework-solving service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would go through the tickers array and if it starts with "S", add it to the sCompanies array.

```
tickers.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
    if (item.startsWith('S')) {
        sCompanies.push(item);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the filter function like this ?

```
// Only return companies starting by "S"
const sCompanies = tickers.filter((companyName) => companyName.startsWith('S'))
```

But if you want to do it with a for loop, you can check this:

```js
// Iterate through this list of tickers to build your new array:
const tickers = ["A", "SAS", "SADS", "ZUMZ"];

//console.log(tickers);

// Define your empty sCompanies array here:
const sCompanies = [];

// Write your loop here:
for (let i = 0; i < tickers.length; i++) {
  tickers[i].startsWith("S") && sCompanies.push(tickers[i]);
}

// Define sLength here:
const sLength = sCompanies.length;

/*
// These lines will log your new array and its length to the console:
*/
console.log(sCompanies);
console.log(sLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

with your loop it would be like this:

```js
for (i = 0; i < tickers.length; i++) {
  if (tickers[i].startsWith('S')) {
    sCompanies.push(tickers[i]);
  }
}
```

OR a bit more modern

```js
for (const i in tickers) {
  if (tickers[i].startsWith('S')) {
    sCompanies.push(tickers[i]);
  }
}
```

Better yet using `for...of` which is for looping arrays.

```js
for (const ticker of tickers) {
  if (ticker.startsWith('S')) {
    sCompanies.push(ticker);
  }
}
```

Or you could do a oneliner like the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the following code back as the model solution, I understood the reason to use this format is incase I wanted to target something other than first letter:

```
if(tickers[i][0] == 'S')
```

Then I could use [1] instead of [0] to target the second letter.